# stream_context_create with HTTP Option based on domain name

Tags: php, xml, xslt, cookies

**How can I tell the streamContext, created with `stream_context_create()` to use different HTTP Headers according to the domain name of a requested URI?**

I'm using XSL to transform an XML on server side (PHP).

To do so, I first create a stream context with some options and apply this stream to `libxml`:

```
$streamContextOptions = array(
    'http' =>array(
        'header'=>$clientHeadersString /* HTTP header */
    )
);
$streamContext = stream_context_create($streamContextOptions);
libxml_set_streams_context($streamContext);
```

Then I load the XML, XSL and do the transform

```
// Load the XML
$xmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDocument->load($xmlURI);

// Load the XSL into
$xslDocument = new DOMDocument();
$xslDocument->load($xslURI);
$xslProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslProcessor->importStylesheet($xslDocument);

// Apply the XSL
$htmlDocument = $xslProcessor->transformToDoc($xmlDocument);
```

In the XSL, I have some `document()` calls so the PHP server calls the specified URIs using the stream context. But I have different domains inside these `document()` calls (let's say I have www.foo.com and www.bar.com).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.foo.com/with-user-agent.xml.php')/root"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.bar.com/with-accept-language.php')/root"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want is to change the HTTP headers the libxml is using when doing the `document()` calls inside the XSL, so I can send [cookies + user-agent] to foo.com, and [other cookies + accept-language] to bar.com when they are requested inside an XSL `document()` call.

I don't want to send "too many" header to foo.com (aka, I don't want to send `Accept-Language` to foo.com) nor to bar.com, and I don't want the cookies to mix (cookies send to foo.com must not be send to bar.com).

Somehow, like:

```
$streamContextOptions = array(
    'http-for-foo' =>array(
        'header'=>$clientHeadersStringForFoo /* HTTP header only when document() calls for foo.com*/
    ),
    'http-for-bar' =>array(
        'header'=>$clientHeadersStringForBar /* HTTP header only when document() calls for bar.com*/
    )
);
```

**Is there a way to tell XSLTProcessor to change the streamOptions depending on the domain requested by `document()` function?**

Comment: Isn't the true problem your external resource is depends on request headers? Imho the resource(s) should be static and cacheable.

Comment: @RolandFranssen No, because the XML resource could be the user's profile data (username, avatar, mail...). So user must be logged in before being able to retrieve this kind of XML.
The returned XML could also be based on `Accept-Language` for localization data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could proxy the request? I.e. `document('//mydomain/?doc=origin-doc')`

This way you can modify the request (e.g. using cURL) to your needs. The doc parameter can be used to conditionally modify the request.

Comment: Thing is I want to be able to process the XSL on client side: the server side process is a fallback in case browser doesn't support XSL.
So, using a proxy, when XSL is parsed on client side, the browser will send `mydomain` credentials (and be proxyed to `otherDomain`) instead of calling `otherDomain` directly with the correct credentials.
I know server side `mydomain` won't have `otherDomain`credentials, but I want `otherDomain` to be called credential-less when on server side, and credential-full when on client side.

Comment: Actually, since Chrome (webkit?) does not accept CORS for XML/XSL documents, I'll use this kind of way, and stuck to local URIs (with one stream context for the whole XSL) poxied by the server if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can not tell about different hosts for stream context options because with the stream I/O operation, the context has been assigned - there is no room with [`libxml_set_streams_context`](http://php.net/libxml_set_streams_context) to differ based on hostname (also for streams in PHP this isn't possible, too. At least AFAIK).

So instead, you need to assign the URI with the appropriate stream options.

In your scenario it seems to me this is most easily done *after* the DOM setup but *before* the transformation by creating [your own external entity loader](http://php.net/libxml_set_external_entity_loader) that is able to differ the context options based on hostname:

```
...

$xslProcessor->importStylesheet($xslDocument);

$httpOptions       = [
    'timeout' => 1,
    'header'  => "User-Agent: Godzilla Gabba Gandalf Client 42.4 - Lord of the XSLT Weed Edition"
];
$httpOptionsByHost = [
    'www.foo.com' => [
        'header' => "X-Secret-Debug-Request-Flag: verbose-verbose-verbose"
    ],
    'www.bar.com' => [
        'header' => "User-Agent: 1' OR TRUE"
    ]
];

libxml_set_external_entity_loader(
    function ($public, $system, $context) use ($httpOptions, $httpOptionsByHost) {

        $url = new Net_URL2($system);
        $url->normalize();
        $host = $url->getHost();

        $options['http'] = [];

        if (isset($httpOptionsByHost[$host])) {
            $options['http'] = $httpOptionsByHost[$host];
        }

        $options['http'] += $httpOptions;

        $context = stream_context_create($options);

        return fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
    }
);

// Apply the XSL
$htmlDocument = $xslProcessor->transformToDoc($xmlDocument);

...
```

You didn't supply the XML in your question nor are the external URIs working, so I could only test partially, but as far as I could validate, this should work.

You might need to differ more in the external entity loader function as you might have additional *other* entities you load that should not be handled equally. But I assume you can figure that out.

Comment: Does `libxml_set_external_entity_loader()` work for `document()` calls inside the XSL? Or do I have to switch and use `entities` inside the XML instead of `document()` inside XSL?

Comment: It works for `document()` calls inside the XSL, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it. In my test I could create two different stream contexts for the two different hostnames you have in the two differen URIs that are inside `document()` inside the XSL file.